# Size of image in customtkinter inside a label

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

This is not error this is a help. I attached a PIL image in custom tkinter

```
cursor.execute("SELECT profileimg FROM dibusersdata WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password))
imag = cursor.fetchone()[0]
imgj = io.BytesIO(imag)
img = im.resize((300,300), Image LANCZOS)
imgg = CTkImage(img)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=imgg, text='')
label.place()
```

i want the image to be resized and be big. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you are using customtkinter, you can resize change the size of the picture by adding the size variable in the CTKImage function, here's how:

```
imgg = CTkImage(img,size(600,600)
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=imgg, text='')
label.place()
```

Assuming you want the label to be the same size as the image or you want the image to cover up the whole label:

```
imgg = CTkImage(img,size(600,600)
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=imgg, text='',width=600,height=600)
label.place()
```

If you need any other help please describe your problem in detail.

Thanks!

Comment: but, i was displaying this img in a frame with width, height, corner_radius = 40 just a circular image. when i try to display the image in that frame, the image exeeds its boundries and gets displayed in a square shape above the frame.

Comment: If u want the image to make itself round from the corners you then have to utilize the Pillow mask function. I would suggest that you should edit the image in third-party software and use that in the frame instead of applying mask. If u still want the mask to be applied lemme know I will sed you a code for that.

Comment: yes, because i want a profile image like thing. because its like a login app and i really not gonna know which resolution of image the user going to choose for his profile, i want to mask it. please help me

Answer (score 0):

So heres the code that will make the your image border_radius round to 40:

```
def create_rounded_resized_image():
    
    imag = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imag))
    img = imag.resize((300,300))
    mask = Image.new("L", (300,300), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.rounded_rectangle([(0, 0), (300,300)], 40, fill=255)
    img.putalpha(mask)
    return img

rounded_resized_image = create_rounded_resized_image()
rounded_resized_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rounded_resized_image)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master = frame,width=300,height=300,image=rounded_resized_photo, text='')
label.pack()
```

The `(300,300)` represents `(width,height)` of image and the `imag = Image.open(io.Bytes(imag))` the `imag` is the source or the path of your bytes image file.

Comment: so i should replace the 300s with my optional height and eidth?

Comment: one doubt, Will it make a perfecty circular image? i am new to this and i dont know much about pil module

Comment: @Rithiksaran No this wouldn't generate a perfect circle for me the code is generating a perfect circle when the `border_radius` is kept at `150` but as you mentioned you want a `border_radius` of `40 ` so I marked that value in my code.

Comment: according to my calculation, to generate a perfect circle, the border radius is 150 and width,height is 300

Comment: i.e 150:300 = 1:2. if i want the width and height as 40, = 1/2 * 40 which gives 20. I set the width and height as 40 and radius as 20 and it worked like a charm for me. thank you very much

Comment: BTW, can we make a border around it?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the code that's generating a perfectly round image for me:

```
def create_rounded_resized_image():
    
    imag = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imag))
    img = imag.resize((300,300))
    mask = Image.new("L", (300,300), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.rounded_rectangle([(0, 0), (300,300)], 150, fill=255)
    # Just change the 150 to your required border_radius in the above line
    img.putalpha(mask)
    return img

rounded_resized_image = create_rounded_resized_image()
rounded_resized_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rounded_resized_image)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master = frame,width=300,height=300,image=rounded_resized_photo, text='')
label.pack()
```